# Set up https on the localhost

Tags: ssl, https, localhost

I have an error occuring on a page that only happens when I access the page through https.  I need to configure https on my local machine for testing but am not sure how to go about it?

EDIT.

Using IIS.  Sorry for not including.

Comment: What error? What server software?

Comment: Which web server are you using for testing? IIS? Apache? These can be set up with SSL fairly easily. Visual Studio's built-in one? I don't think this one can.

Comment: and unless it's a mixed secure / insecure content error you can probably just fake it in your code somehow.

Comment: I am using IIS.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IIS then go here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=56fc92ee-a71a-4c73-b628-ade629c89499&DisplayLang=en
and download the tookit.
In there you'll find a utility called SelfSSL.  You can set up a certificate locally that'll get you through development.  If I recall the command is:

```
selfssl /T /N: cn="your_computer_name"
```

I know the answer is a bit late but hopefully it'll help someone.

Comment: Alternatively, FWIW, you can run Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and use the AutoResponder to redirect HTTPS requests to your HTTP endpoint. As far as your browser knows, everything's happening over HTTPS.